# How does a "Schema changed after the target table was created" error occur?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I hit this error while my web application was trying to execute a SELECT INTO on a MSSQL 2005 database.  I really have two questions:

1. What does this error mean and how does this happen?
2. Is there a way to prevent these errors by coding in a different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides the obvious, that somebody changed the table while the code was executing, it could be a naming conflict with temp tables created in the SQL.  It could be that there are two temp tables with different schemas, but they have the same name.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this error if a database trigger(AFTER CREATE_TABLE) changes the table, when using SELECT INTO.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can get this when you have the 
SELECT * INTO #TABLE FROM TABLE
used within a stored procedure and it is run multiple times concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify dbo. as the schema for the first table.