# SELECT INTO breaks DDL/DML trigger but CREATE TABLE followed by INSERT works?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl, database-trigger, dml

In SQL Server 2017 (SSMS v18.3) I'm using a DDL trigger to create `output` tables for given `input` tables.

I then create a DML trigger on the `input` tables to populate the `output` tables.

This works as intended when using `CREATE TABLE` followed by `INSERT INTO`

When using `SELECT INTO` the query throws this error:

```
Msg 539, Level 16, State 78, Line 50
Schema changed after the target table was created. Rerun the Select Into query.
```

and while the `input`, `output`, and trigger gets created, none of the data is inserted.

I've tried CATCH RETRY on every part of the query but I can't pin it down.

**How can I overcome this error while still using `SELECT INTO` to create tables in the `[input]` schema?**

And what schema are `SELECT INTO` tables created in?

Here's a [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=db65a8f956045cf1376b35ff9e782642) demonstrating this issue

Here's another [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb51c3b16e5fffdd11974f34dc49936e) that demonstrates the same issue contained in one schema with different table names.

And here's my code:

```
USE TestData
GO
/*--
  CREATE SCHEMA input
  GO
  CREATE SCHEMA output
  GO
--*/
;IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE name = 'CreateDMLTriggerOnTable') DROP TRIGGER CreateDMLTriggerOnTable ON DATABASE;
GO 
CREATE TRIGGER CreateDMLTriggerOnTable ON DATABASE
AFTER CREATE_TABLE
AS   
  declare @schemaname as varchar(128) = 'input'
  --Only act on tables in our target scheme [input]
  ;IF EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','varchar(128)') <> @schemaname RETURN;

  declare @tablename as varchar(128) = EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
  declare @tb_input as varchar(261) = '[input].[' + @tablename + ']'
  declare @tb_output as varchar(261) = '[output].[' + @tablename + ']'

  --Create a matching [output] table for the newly created [input] table
  declare @tmpsql as nvarchar(max)
  set @tmpsql = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @tb_output + ' ( CountOfRows tinyint ) '
  print isnull(@tmpsql,'NULLED!')
  EXEC(@tmpsql)

  --Populate [output] with data from [input] table using DML trigger
  set @tmpsql = ''
  set @tmpsql = @tmpsql + ';CREATE TRIGGER InsertState_' + @tablename + ' ON ' + @tb_input + ' FOR INSERT AS '
  set @tmpsql = @tmpsql + ';INSERT INTO ' + @tb_output + ' SELECT count(*) CountOfRows FROM inserted'
  print isnull(@tmpsql,'NULLED!')
  EXEC(@tmpsql)
GO

;IF OBJECT_ID('input.firsttest','U') is not null DROP TABLE [input].[firsttest]
;IF OBJECT_ID('output.firsttest','U') is not null DROP TABLE [output].[firsttest]
;IF OBJECT_ID('input.secondtest','U') is not null DROP TABLE [input].[secondtest]
;IF OBJECT_ID('output.secondtest','U') is not null DROP TABLE [output].[secondtest]

--As long as the table is created before any inserts the trigger is also created and both tables are populated
;CREATE TABLE input.firsttest ( AnyColumn tinyint)
INSERT INTO input.firsttest VALUES (10),(20),(30)

SELECT 'input1' tb  , * FROM [input].[firsttest]
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'output1' tb , * FROM [output].[firsttest]

GO

--This is where things go wrong. Trying to create a trigger on a table that is in the process of being created by a SELECT INTO statement throws error 539
SELECT * INTO [input].[secondtest] FROM [input].[firsttest]

GO

--No data goes into either of the tables. However, 
SELECT 'input2a' tb, * FROM [input].[secondtest]
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'output2a' tb, * FROM [output].[secondtest]

GO

--This works and shows that the trigger is created on the table.
INSERT INTO [input].[secondtest] SELECT * FROM [input].[firsttest]

GO

--The table is populated as it should be by the SELECT INTO statement
SELECT 'input2b' tb, * FROM [input].[secondtest]
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'output2b' tb, * FROM [output].[secondtest]
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you can't use `SELECT INTO` twice. That command is used to create a new table based on a query's results. You can't use it a second time since the table is *already* created.

Comment: Apart from that, there's no SQL Server v18.3. That's the SSMS version, a client tool. What is the actual SQL Server version? SQL Server versions are based on the release year, eg 2014, 2016, 2017

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've fixed the SQL Server + SSMS versions in my question, thanks. But I'm not running SELECT INTO twice, I'm creating a table once, and then selecting from that table into a new table.

Comment: FYI `;` is a statement **terminator**, it's goes at the end of statements, not at the start of them. :)

Comment: Honestly, the looks like an XY Problem to me. What are you actually trying to achieve with this `TRIGGER`?

Comment: @Larnu I'm trying to insert data from one table (A) to another (B) as soon as it's created and whenever an insert occurs on table (A). (B) should have the same name as (A) in a different schema. I will not know what the name of (A) will be. ``CREATE`` and ``INSERT INTO`` work fine, but I need it to work with  ``SELECT INTO`` as well

Answer (score 0):

As you are using, select * INTO [input].[secondtest] the below statement creates the permanent table on fly with the same schema and properties as of [input].[firsttest]. If the table already exists and you perform INTO [input].[secondtest] then sql server throws the mentioned error so if you want multiple inserts to take place in the trigger so go with plain insert logic

```
INSERT INTO [input].[secondtest](AnyColumn) SELECT AnyColumn FROM [input].[firsttest]
```

Instead of

```
SELECT * INTO [input].[secondtest] FROM [input].[firsttest]
```

Comment: ``[input].[secondtest]`` doesn't exist before ``SELECT INTO`` so are you saying that ``SELECT INTO`` creates the table twice? Part of this problem is that I need to be able to use ``SELECT  INTO`` to create tables

Comment: [input].[secondtest] doesn't exist before SELECT INTO [input].[secondtest] will create table once.  if it encounters the SELECT INTO [input].[secondtest] statement again it doesnt create the table instead it throws error stating the table already exists.

Comment: There is only 1 select into statement

Comment: Please follow this link you might get answer for your question you are facing exactly the same situation as mentioned in the link provided. As you are having same table name (secondtest) and different schemas ([input] & [output])    
[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162205/how-does-a-schema-changed-after-the-target-table-was-created-error-occur)

Comment: Hi @varun thanks for getting back to me. I've read through the questions and answers you linked me to but I'm still not sure how to solve this problem. I've adjusted my code in [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bb51c3b16e5fffdd11974f34dc49936e) to use the same schema with different table names but the error persists, so it's not a naming conflict. Is the SELECT INTO creating the table in a temporary schema before the insert and then losing it somehow?

Comment: replace 
SELECT AnyColumn INTO input.secondtest FROM input.firsttest
with
CREATE TABLE input.secondtest ( AnyColumn tinyint)
INSERT INTO input.secondtest
SELECT AnyColumn  FROM [input].[firsttest] and check if you are still facing the issue.